# Method Invocation failed system.string error

Tags: powershell

Morning,

I'm trying to use a CSV file with a list of users and automate the process to set an AD users extensionAttribute15 back to the "notset" value.

I use a similar code to populate the attribute, the CSV file consists of just two things, the users LAN ID and the value for the attribute.

Populating the field is not the problem, changing the values back to "not set" has been.

Here is the code I am using.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory  
Import-CSV "code.csv" | % { 
$User = $_.cn 
$user.Put(“extensionAttribute15”, @())
$user.SetInfo()  
}
```

and here are the errors.

Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'Put'.
At attribute.ps1:4 char:10
+ $user.Put <<<< (“extensionAttribute15”, @())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Put:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'SetInfo'.
At attribute.ps1:5 char:14
+ $user.SetInfo <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetInfo:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks,

Comment: Your problem is what the errors are telling you: you're trying to call methods that don't exist for a string. Start by converting your string into a user object `$member = get-adGroupMember -identity $User` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx  http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-active-directory/

Answer (score 3):

When you read in a CSV file, the resulting objects are just simple property bags.  They don't support any special methods, they just hold flat data.  There is nothing in these objects that isn't present in the text of the CSV file itself.

If you want to obtain a rich object which has Active Directory context and capabilities, you will need to obtain one from a cmdlet in the ActiveDirectory module.

Something like this is probably along the lines you need

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory  
Import-CSV "code.csv" | % { 
    $user = Get-ADUser $_.cn  # get a rich object from the AD module, by passing a string 
    $user.Put(“extensionAttribute15”, @())
    $user.SetInfo()  
}
```